# How to check value length with Zapier?

Tags: javascript, zapier

I need help with my Zap from Zapier.
My aim is to read a value of a hubspot contact and check if the  value is not set. I made a first try with Javascript.

```
let x= inputData.discord;
if (x) {
  output = [{id: 123, hello: "true"}];
}else if(!x) {
  output = [{id: 123, hello: "empty"}];
} else {
  output = [{id: 123, hello: "not empty"}];
}
```

My problem is the following:
If the field is empty and not set the correct result comes with "empty".
If the field has a value empty is delivered too, so the code thinks the value is empty but it isnt.

I have also tried to check the length attribute but I get the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

I hope there is a solution to check that.